# How to get a value of pressed <button type='button'?

Tags: php, html

is there a way (without using JS) to get into PHP the value of pressed

`<button type='button' name='bobby' value='".$value."'> .. </button>`?

In latter code, I have the submit button as well (to submit all form).

Comment: Unless the button triggers a form submssion, there is **NO** way for server-side PHP to see what the client did. That's why there's Javascript - for executing client-side code.

Comment: Why not use a checkbox or a radio button to get the value when the form submits?

Comment: @AdRock: I need to process the next content via JS (generating content according to the value of pressed button).

Answer (score 0):

As from what I've experienced before, PHP doesn't work. JavaScript is the bet way to set the value. You cannot get the value of the button in a form btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to find the form submission `isset` and `$_POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['bobby'])){
 echo "You pressed the button";
}else{
 echo "No action triggered yet";
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type='submit' name='bobby' value='<?php echo $value;?>'></button>
```